# DataGrid Items collection doesn't always refresh

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` bound to an `ObservableCollection<Client>`.
I have a `UserControl` which is responsible to apply a filter on the collection from a `Textbox` value like this:

```
private void UCFilterBox_SearchTextChanged(object sender, string e)
{
    var coll = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dgClients.ItemsSource);
    coll.Filter = o =>
    {
        var c = o as Client;
        if (c != null)
        {
            bool ret =  (the filter...)

            return ret;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Then I have a `TextBlock` which is bound to the `DataGrid`'s `Items` collection like this:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
            Margin="215,0,0,5"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SmallTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding ElementName=dgClients, Path=Items.Count}" />
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SmallTextBlockStyle}" 
               Text="{Binding ElementName=dgClients, Path=Items.Count, Converter={StaticResource ClientSingleOrPluralConverter}, StringFormat={} {0}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

This is working correctly, and each time the `DataGrid` is filtered, the value changes accordingly.

However, I have another `TextBlock` bound to the `DataGrid`'s `Items` collection, which is responsible of showing the sum of the displayed data, and this one is not updating !

```
<TextBlock Margin="5"
           FontWeight="Bold"
           Text="{Binding ElementName=dgClients,
                          Path=Items,
                          Converter={StaticResource CalculateSumConvertor},
                          StringFormat={}{0:C}}" />
```

The `CalculateSumConvertor` is only hit once at the binding of the `DataGrid` and then no more.

Here is the converter:

```
public class CalculateSumConvertor: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var clients = value as ItemCollection;

        if (clients != null)
        {
            return clients.Cast<Client>().Sum(c => c.FieldToSum);
        }
        else
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrongly here ?

Comment: It's because DataGrid doesn't notify about changes in its items. Why can't you bind the textbox to the original collection directly?

Comment: I wanted to respect MVVM as close as possible, so in my understanding, filtering on a `CollectionViewSource` is a view matter.  I know a solution could be to expose the `CollectionViewSource` object directly in my ViewModel, but I'd prefer to do it otherwise if it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your binding to the following and change your converter to an IMultiValueConverter

```
    <TextBlock Margin="5"
       FontWeight="Bold">
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CalculateSumConvertor}" StringFormat="{}{0:C}">
                <Binding ElementName="dgClients" Path="Items" />
                <Binding ElementName="dgClients" Path="Items.Count" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
```

Converter:

```
class CalculateSumConvertor : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var clients = values[0] as ItemCollection;
        ...
    }




}
```

Comment: Indeed, it works, many thanks, I didn't think to that at all !  Does it mean that on a `MultiBinding`, as soon as a `Binding` is updated, every other `Binding` is re-read ?

Comment: Actually, bindings cache their values and will not be re-read unless forced to by a PropertyChanged event.